# Where do you manually insert assertions into an automated coded ui test's code in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automation

I am currently automating smoke tests and I am trying to learn how to manually insert assertions with C# into the UImap.Designer.cs file. I am trying to learn how to do this manually but I have no direction on where to put the assertions and all the literature I am finding only covers how to add assertions with the CodedUI Test Builder tool that is included with VS2010. Can anyone direct me to where I need to insert the assertions?

Answer (score 0):

Do not include anything in the designer file. It will get overwritten every time you rebuild a UIMap.

Second, generally speaking, this should be in the test themselves. When you look at a test class, it should be easily visible about **what** it's asserting and verifying. Assertions should not be buried into UIMap's.

Third, is there any reason why you have chosen Coded UI? Something like Selenium will give you much more flexibility, but I am just mentioning this in case your project has the flexibility to change.

Comment: Well, the company I am working for is switching to using TFS and we are integrating QA testing with VS2010. Thanks for the advice on the designer file.